# Change Root Folder Directory and Redirect to HTTPS with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I don't know much about the .htaccess file and need some assistance please.  I have a few websites hosted one one CPanel account.  I didn't want to have my "main" site stored directly in the public_html folder, so I moved it into a subfolder and then found this .htaccess configuration that allows me to load my main site from that subdirectory. So that is working.

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example_directory/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example.com/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example.com/index.html
```

So as I said, the above .htaccess will allow me to store my site files in a different folder rather than right at the root.  But now I'm trying to force a redirect for this site over **https** as well. I found this site here:

[Force Website to Use SSL](http://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/website/ssl/force-website-to-use-ssl)

But, since I really don't understand the .htaccess file I'm having trouble integrating these two features together.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain I figured this out myself. I just simply had to add this to the end of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

and it works like a charm.  Full .htaccess file looks like this, which changes the folder directory for the site to use and then forces it over https.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example_directory/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example.com/index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```